# how to find exact cursor position in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I have tried to get the exact position to drop the content in tinymce. But not able to find the cursor position and not able to fetch the data values takes place. Its only fetching values in previous position.

Please help me.

I have tried below code,

tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getRng() - here we can't able to find the exact position. it fetch only previoous position.

```
         ed.on("drop", function($event) {
            if($event.preventDefault) {
                $event.preventDefault();
            }
            if($event.stopPropagation()) {
                $event.stopPropagation();
            }

            if ($event.dataTransfer) {
                var data = $event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                var $data = angular.fromJson(data);
            }
        });
```

In drop also we cant able to find the exact position.

Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one.

I wrote two functions. One to get the absolute cursor position in tinymce and one to set the cursor to a specified cursor position. Plus two helpfull functions to set the caret in the editor and one to get the block element in which the actual caret is to be found.

I have those functions placed inside my own custom tinymce plugin *myownplugin*, but you may put those functions where you like.

Here they are:

```
    // gets the caret offset to the editor start
    get_caret_offset: function()
    {
        var ed = this.editor;

        var range = ed.selection.getRng(1);
        var copied_range = range.cloneRange();
        var subtract_from_index = 0;

        // count returns
        var index = $(ed.plugins.myownplugin.p_of(range.startContainer)).index();
        var add_to_offset = 0;

        // add 1 for each empty paragraph
        var $children = $(ed.getBody()).children();

        // some node contents need to be subtracted from the offset later on.
        // free paragraphs count for example
        var subtract = 0;
        var rte_starts = 0;
        for (var i=0; i < index; i++)
        {
            var child_node = $children.eq(i).get(0);
            if (child_node)
            {
                if (child_node.nodeName == 'RTEPHTAG')
                {
                    subtract_from_index++;

                    if (child_node.className == "start")
                    {
                        subtract = 0;
                    }
                    else subtract = 0;
                }

                if (subtract && (child_node.nodeName == 'P' || child_node.nodeName == 'OL' || child_node.nodeName == 'UL'))
                {
                    subtract_from_index += child_node.textContent.replace(re_exspaces,'')
                        .replace( /\ufeff/g, '' )
                        .replace( /\u00ad/g, '' )
                        .replace( /&#65279;/g, '')
                        .replace( /&#173;/g, '')
                        .replace( /&shy;/g, '').length + 1;
                }
                // count bBRs
                else if(child_node.nodeName == 'P' || child_node.nodeName == 'OL' || child_node.nodeName == 'UL')
                {
                    add_to_offset += $(child_node).find('br').length;
                }
            }
        }

        // copy range to be able to calculate characters to the start of the initial range
        copied_range.setStart(ed.getBody().firstChild, 0);

        // caret paragraph needs to be counted too?
        if(subtract)
        {
            if (index)
            {
                var endnode = $children.eq(index - 1).get(0);
                if (endnode) copied_range.setEndAfter(endnode);
                else copied_range.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            }
            else return 0;
        }
        else copied_range.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);

        var str = copied_range.toString();
        subtract_from_index += ( str.match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF]/g) || [] ).length;

        var caret_offset = str
            .replace(re_exspaces,'')
            .replace( /\ufeff/g, '' )
            .replace( /\u00ad/g, '' )
            .replace( /&#65279;/g, '')
            .replace( /&#173;/g, '')
            .replace( /&shy;/g, '').length + index + add_to_offset + rte_starts - subtract_from_index;

        // add BRs in the actual paragraph?
        var p_end = ed.plugins.myownplugin.p_of(range.endContainer);
        if(range.endContainer && range.endContainer.nodeName != 'BODY')
        {
            if (p_end){
                copied_range.setStartBefore(p_end);
            }
        }

        return caret_offset;
    },

    // sets the caret according to the offset
    set_caret_offset: function(offset, scroll_into_view)
    {
        function get_count(where_str, search_str) {
            var m = where_str.match(new RegExp(search_str.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "g"));
            return m ? m.length:0;
        }

        var ed = this.editor;


        // Check: enough content to set caret?
        if (!offset)
            ed.plugins.myownplugin.setCursor(ed, ed.getBody().firstChild, 1);

        var $body = $(ed.getBody());
        var content = ed.getContent({format : 'text', no_events : 1})
            .replace(re_exspaces,'')
            .replace( /\ufeff/g, '' )
            .replace( /\u00ad/g, '' )
            .replace( /&#65279;/g, '')
            .replace( /&#173;/g, '')
            .replace( /&shy;/g, '');
        var content_length = content.length + $body.find('br').length - ( content.match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF]/g) || [] ).length;

        if (content_length <= offset)
        {
            // set caret to the end of the editor
            ed.plugins.myownplugin.setCursor(ed, ed.getBody().lastChild, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            var offset_till_now = 0;
            var node = ed.getBody().firstChild;
            var rng;
            var counter = 0;
            while (node && offset > offset_till_now)
            {
                var br_count = 0;

                // Offset muss verringert werden, da Indesign Ps und BRs als Zeichen zählt
                if (counter && (node.nodeName == "BR" || node.nodeName == "P" || node.nodeName == "OL" || node.nodeName == "UL"))
                {
                    offset = offset - 1;
                }
                counter++;

                if (node.nodeName == "P" || node.nodeName == "OL" || node.nodeName == "UL")
                {
                    br_count = $(node).find('br').length;
                }

                var textContent = node.textContent
                    .replace(re_exspaces,'')
                    .replace( /\ufeff/g, '' )
                    .replace( /\u00ad/g, '' )
                    .replace( /&#65279;/g, '')
                    .replace( /&#173;/g, '')
                    .replace( /&shy;/g, '');

                var length = textContent.length + br_count - ( textContent.match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF]/g) || [] ).length;

                // textnode?
                if (node && node.nodeType == 3)
                {
                    if (offset <= offset_till_now + length)
                    {
                        rng = ed.selection.getRng(1);
                        rng.setStart(node, offset - offset_till_now);
                        rng.setEnd(node, offset - offset_till_now);

                        offset_till_now = offset; // fertig
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node = node.nextSibling;
                        offset_till_now += length;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // caret to be inserted here ?
                    if (offset < offset_till_now + length)
                    {
                        // nur text nodes als Kinder?
                        // dann schreibe den textknoten neu und setze die Range entsprechend
                        // ansonsten weiter mit dem ersten Kind
                        if (!node.children.length)
                        {
                            var textnode = ed.getDoc().createTextNode(node.textContent);
                            node.innerHTML = '';
                            node.appendChild(textnode);

                            rng = ed.selection.getRng(1);
                            rng.setStart(textnode, offset - offset_till_now);
                            rng.setEnd(textnode, offset - offset_till_now);

                            var copied_range = rng.cloneRange();
                            copied_range.setStart(textnode, 0);
                            copied_range.setEnd(textnode, offset - offset_till_now);

                            var t = copied_range.toString();
                            var add_to_index = ( t.match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF]/g) || [] ).length;

                            rng.setStart(textnode, offset - offset_till_now + add_to_index);
                            rng.setEnd(textnode, offset - offset_till_now + add_to_index);

                            offset_till_now = offset; // fertig
                        }
                        node = node.firstChild;
                    }
                    // caret needs to be set after this node
                    else
                    {
                        if (offset == offset_till_now + length)
                        {
                            // set caret to start of node
                            ed.plugins.myownplugin.setCursor(ed, node, 0);
                            offset_till_now = offset; // fertig
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // get following node
                            node = node.nextSibling;
                            offset_till_now += length;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // scrollinto view
        if (scroll_into_view)
        {
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<span class="set_caret_marker">\ufeff</span>');
            setTimeout(function() {
                var $marker = $(ed.getBody()).find('.set_caret_marker');
                if ($marker.length)
                {
                    $marker.get(0).scrollIntoView();
                    ed.selection.select($marker.get(0));
                    $marker.remove();
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    },

    // sets the cursor position (start defines if the caret is to be placed at the start)
    setCursor: function (ed, element, start)
    {
        // caret may appear inside lis only
        if (element.nodeName == "UL" || element.nodeName == "OL")
        {
            $element = $(element);
            element = start ? $element.find('li:first').get(0) : $element.find('li:last').get(0);
        }

        var doc = ed.getDoc();
        var edwin = ed.getWin();

        var range = ed.selection.dom.createRng();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        range.collapse(start);
        var sel = ed.selection.getSel();
        sel && sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel && sel.addRange(range);
    },

    // returns the block parent element of the actual element
    // stopper defines a node at which we will stop
    p_of: function (node, stopper)
    {
        stopper = stopper ? stopper.toUpperCase() : null;

        while (node)
        {
            if (node.nodeName == 'BODY') { return null; }
            if (node.nodeName == 'P' || node.nodeName == 'UL' || node.nodeName == 'OL' || node.nodeName == stopper) { return node; }
            else { node = node.parentNode; }
        }
        return null;
    },
```

I hope this is usefull for some of you.

Comment: But i need cursor position while drag and drop attributes in inside tinymce. Still i dont get the curosr position.

Comment: then you will need to listen for the propper drag  & drop events and get the position using the information provided there

Comment: While drop event we cant able to get the position. it goes to the previous postion or it goes to first